# Error C1083: Cannot Open Include file. File included properly in code

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

So I've looked into this issue, and nothing has helped me so far. I've read numerous topics, many people say the same things about it not actually being able to find the file. In my project, I can right click the header where it is including (and giving the fatal error) and it will open the header file, everything loads works perfectly fine in the editor, but Visual Studio still tells me that the file cannot be found while compiling. I've double checked the spelling, I've added the double quotation marks around the includes and additional libraries, and removed them, and nothing is working.

I'm trying to include the header files for MySQL. I added and tried the include and library directories as well as libmysql.lib to the proper locations (Additional include directories, additional library directories, and Additional dependencies) with (to my knowledge) most combinations of directory paths.

The folder structure has the mysqlcon folder in the solution directory, and the project in its own folder. When I include the mysqlcon\include and lib folders. I tried:

- ..\mysqlcon\include
- "..\mysqlcon\include"
- $(SolutionDir)\mysqlcon\include
- $(SolutionDir)\\mysqlcon\\include

Nothing seems to be working. I'm at a total loss. I even rebuilt the entire project today, got all the dependencies, references, build order, files, vcprojs redone, and I'm back staring at the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution... I'm not sure why it worked before, but I changed

```
#include "mysql.h"
```

to

```
#include "..\mysqlcon\include\mysql.h"
```

and it worked perfectly.